# Azure Active Directory Authentication within Streamlit

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, azure-ad-msal, streamlit

I am trying to test an Azure Directory Authentication within a streamlit app, when I do this on my http://localhost:8501 it works perfectly as expected. Hitting the login button prompts me to login on the Microsoft authentication page and returns the token values in a dictionary.

however, when I have other users on my network test this by accessing the app on my network url, when they hit login the Microsoft authentication popup on Chrome opens up on my machine instead of theirs.

I cant seem to understand whats causing this and would appreciate any insight.

```
import streamlit as st
import msal
import webbrowser
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import urllib



client_id = "xxxx"
tenant_id = "xxxx"
client_secret = "xxxx"
redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8501/"
scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
endpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id, client_credential=client_secret, authority=authority, verify=False
)

def get_token_from_cache():
    accounts = app.get_accounts()
    if not accounts:
        return None
    
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes, account=accounts[0])
    if "access_token" in result:
        return result["access_token"]
    else:
        return None

def login():
    flow = app.initiate_auth_code_flow(
        scopes=scopes)

    if "auth_uri" not in flow:
        return st.write("Failed with token")

    auth_uri = flow["auth_uri"]

    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get(auth_uri)

    WebDriverWait(browser, 200).until(
        EC.url_contains(redirect_uri))
    
    redirected_url = browser.current_url
    url = urllib.parse.urlparse(redirected_url)
    # parse the query string to get a dictionary of {key: value}

    query_params = dict(urllib.parse.parse_qsl(url.query))
    

    #code = query_params.get('code')[0]
    
    result = app.acquire_token_by_auth_code_flow(flow,query_params, scopes=scopes)
    
    browser.quit()
    return result


if st.button("Login"):
    token = get_token_from_cache()
    if not token:
        token = login()

    st.write(st.experimental_get_query_params())
    if token:
        st.write("Logged in successfully!")
        st.write(token)
    else:
        st.write("Failed to login")
```

I believe the issue is that when my users are accessing the app on the network url, after hitting login, the part of the code with webdriver.Chrome() is running on my machine as it is the source of the app hosted on the network url, however, I'm not sure if that is the issue and what the fix would be to make the login popup on chrome to appear on the user's local machine instead!

the source of this code: https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/adding-azure-active-directory-sign-in-sign-out-using-msal-python-handling-redirects/37032